# Error IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2

Tags: spring-boot

I have a problem, why generate this error?

I want more comments to be placed in a bug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXBRD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOD7K.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, please remember to post error and code as text not images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.